# Going up the object hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop, reference, openframeworks

Hi so I've got some nice tree hierarchy of objects in program i'm working on. I've came across a problem with communicating the bottom to top way. How I have it set up right now is that in every constructor I pass a reference to object creating the new object. Simple structure would look like this:
[Controller] -> [World] -> [Object]

Going up one layer (from world to controller or from object to world) is OK. But where the problem starts to occur is when I try to go up 2 layers.
Here is a simplified structure of how I have set it up:

Controller.h:

```
#include "World.h"

Class Controller {
public:
   Controller() {
      _worlds.push_back(World(*this));
   )

   void update() { // Called on a loop from main program loop
      _worlds[0].update(); // Calls update of active world, in this case world[0]
   }

   vector<World> _worlds;

   Camera _camera; // class with checkIfInView function
}
```

World.h:

```
#Include "Object.h"

Class Controller;

Class World {
   World(Controller& ref) : _controller(ref) {
      _objects.push_back(Object(*this));
      _controller._camera.doStuff(); // works OK
   }

   void update() {
      for (auto& i : _objects)
         i.update();
   }

   vector<Object> _objects;
   Controller& _controller;
}
```

Object.h:

```
Class World;

Class Object {
   Object(World& ref) : _world(ref) {}
   void update();

   World& _world;
}
```

Object.cpp:

```
#include "Controller.h"
#include "World.h"

void Object::update() {
   _world._controller._camera.checkIfInView(*this); // Read access violation
}
```

Controller hold one single camera object which is responsible for what is being shown. What I need is a way for Objects to call checkIfInView to know if they should render or not. Is there any other way to do this or a way to fix it?

EDIT: Updated code.

Comment: You are not showing any effective code: how you initialize the structure, how you try to access it, so it's impossible to give you a precise answer.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the problem (given your description, that might be a 10 to 15 line program). [Edit] your question and copy-paste that short, complete program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: What service does the controller provide? What is Object? 

From a design perspective, you should have a World object that owns the Objects within it; no controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

Let's look at your nice chain, starting with the `Controller` constructor.  As it's the top object of your hierarchy, it the start of the construction. I imagine that in `main()` you have something like

```
Controller c;
```

This will cause the constructor to be called:

```
 Controller() {
    _worlds.push_back(World(*this));    // !!! 
 }
```

`World(*this)` will create a new temporary world that you'll push into the vector of worlds of your controller.  The temporary object only exists for the time of the expression in which it appears.

The **temporary** World will then be constructed with

```
World(Controller& ref) : _controller(ref) {  // ref to controller is kept 
    _objects.push_back(Object(*this));  // ouch!!! 
    _controller._camera.doStuff(); // works OK
}
```

Now an object will be created which refers to *this world.  Ouch!!  Remember that that world is temporary ?  At the end of the construction it will be deleted, so that all objects will refer to a C++ object that no longer exists and hence the UB which happen to produce the segmentation fault in your case.

#### The start of a solution

The design that you have is quite delicate. Think twice if you couldn't find a safer design pattern.  If you want nevertheless to pursue in this direction, avoid creating objects using temporary items: create dynamically allocated ones instead.

```
Controller() {
    _worlds.push_back(*new World(*this));    // !!! risk of leakage 
}
```

The next thing would be to use pointers instead of references:

```
Controller() {
    _worlds.push_back(new World(*this));    // risk of leakage 
}
```

Of course, you'd need to change the rest of the code accordingly, to work with pointers.

The next thing would be to opt for shared pointers: this avoids risk of leakage:

```
Controller() {
    _worlds.push_back(make_shared<World>(*this));    // risk of leakage 
}
```

In the adaptation of your code you'd then need to make a difference between shared_ptr in your vectors, which refers to the object, and weak_ptr to the parten objects, to indicate tha the parent is now shared owned by the child but by another object.

#### A better solution ?

I warn you that it will not be a piece of cake.  As soon as you have pointers, you'd need to take care of the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) for each class.

Many issues arise from:

1) the nested construction -> may be worth considering the builder design pattern 
2) the risk of mixing of static objects and dynamically created objects, never knowing which kind is the parent.  -> may be worth using a protected/private constructor and use a factory method for making sure that all objects are always dynamic objects.

Comment: Doing _worlds.push_back(World(*this)) inserts a copy of that temporary object so it won't die after constructor ends, doesnt it?. Also I tried to give World some integer value and change it in Object::update(). Then doing _controller._camera.doStuff() in World::update(). Both works. Also I'm not sure if I stated clearly enough that this whole program run in an infinite loop that calls Controller::update() over and over again. And the rule of 3... well I didn't want to use dynamically allocated items to not worry about memory. Last option which I would avoid if possible would be unique_ptr.

Comment: It's difficult to give explanation wen there are Objects and there are objects.  So yes, the push_back creates a copy of your temporary object.  But before it gets copied, it creates an `Object` object, which will keep a reference to the temporary world object.  This reference will not be updated, so the `Object` object (and its copy in the vector) will have an invalid _world reference.

Comment: Ok so I finally realized what you were saying that the Object get's wrong reference to World. So I've changed vector<World> to vector<unique_ptr<World>> and _worlds.push_back(World(*this)) to _worlds.push_back(make_uniqe(*this)) and it all seems to be working as I want. Thanks :)